# sweet alert continue submitting form on confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, sweetalert

I've this sweetalert triggered on submit of a form.

```
$(".swa-confirm").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: $(this).data("swa-title"),
            text: $(this).data("swa-text"),
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#cc3f44",
            confirmButtonText: $(this).data("swa-btn-txt"),
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            html: false
        }, function() {

        }
        );
    });
```

but on clicking confirm I want it to continue submiting the form...

Bad ideas come to mind, like:

```
var confirmed = false;
$(".swa-confirm").on("submit", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!confirmed) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: $(this).data("swa-title"),
            text: $(this).data("swa-text"),
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#cc3f44",
            confirmButtonText: $(this).data("swa-btn-txt"),
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            html: false
        }, function() {
            confirmed = true;
            $this.submit();
        });
    }
});
```

or moving swa to button click instead of on submit, and using on submit of a form.

but I don't like this solution, it looks frankesteini to me. Surely there is a better way

Answer (score 39):

```
$('#btn-submit').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) form.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you are missing a closing semi colon ; but other than that I like your answer ;)

Comment: This won't do any form validations though

Comment: @Abhijeet check https://stackoverflow.com/a/69026840/823454

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is late but it might help someone in the future, I've used this with success for submitting forms with sweetalert confirmations.

```
 $('#form_id').submit(function (e, params) {
        var localParams = params || {};

        if (!localParams.send) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

           //additional input validations can be done hear

    swal({
                title: "Confirm Entry",
                text: "Are you sure all entries are correct",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#6A9944",
                confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
                cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                closeOnConfirm: true
            }, function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    $(e.currentTarget).trigger(e.type, { 'send': true });
                } else {

              //additional run on cancel  functions can be done hear

            }
        });
});
```

Comment: It is even better if you put the whole swal function inside the if loop after the preventDefault.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another example, asking the user to confirm via checkbox.

#### HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
    <button type="submit" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: 'Confirm',
        input: 'checkbox',
        inputValue: 0,
        inputPlaceholder: ' I agree with the Terms',
        confirmButtonText: 'Continue',
        inputValidator: function (result) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (result) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject('You need to agree with the Terms');
                }
            })
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a little more elegant:

```
$(".swa-confirm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: $(this).data("swa-title"),
        text: $(this).data("swa-text"),
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#cc3f44",
        confirmButtonText: $(this).data("swa-btn-txt"),
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        html: false
    }, function(){
        $(".swa-confirm").off("submit").submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**100% Working!!**

Do some little trick using attribute. In your form add an attribute like *data-flag* in your form, assign "0" as false.

```
<form class="swa-confirm" data-flag="0">
    //your inputs
</form>
```

In your jquery.

```
$(".swa-confirm").on("click", function(e) {
    $flag = $(this).attr('data-flag');

    if($flag==0){
        e.preventDefault(); //to prevent submitting

        swal({
            title: $(this).data("swa-title"),
            text: $(this).data("swa-text"),
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#cc3f44",
            confirmButtonText: $(this).data("swa-btn-txt"),
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            html: false
        }, function( confirmed ) {
            if( confirmed ){
                // if confirmed change the data-flag to 1 (as true), to submit
                $('.swa-confirm').attr('data-flag', '1');
                $('.swa-confirm').submit();
            }
        });
    }

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

function testalert(){

```
swal(

    {
        title              : "Are you sure?",
        text               : "You want to save?",
        type               : "warning",
        allowEscapeKey     : false,
        allowOutsideClick  : false,
        showCancelButton   : true,
        confirmButtonColor : "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText  : "Yes",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnConfirm     : false
    }, 

    function (isConfirm) {

        if (isConfirm) {
            profileinfo.submit();
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

);
```

}

Comment: <button id="prty_form_save" type="button" 
onclick="return testalert();">SAVE</button>
button type must be button ( dont use input type= submit)

Answer (score 2):

```
var form = $(this).parents('form');   
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons:[
            'No, cancel it!',
            'Yes, I am sure!'
            ],
            }).then(function(isConfirm){        
                if(isConfirm){ 
                        form.submit();
                } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the class .swa-confirm to the input submit

```
$(".swa-confirm").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: $(this).data("swa-title"),
        text: $(this).data("swa-text"),
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#cc3f44",
        confirmButtonText: $(this).data("swa-btn-txt"),
        closeOnConfirm: true,
        html: false
    }, function( confirmed ) {
        if( confirmed )
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

First prevent the button event. After, launch the sweetalert and if "confirmed" is true then submit #my-form element.

Sorry for my bad english, regards from Mexico, I used Google translate :v.

Comment: You should do it using submit not click cause most of browsers right now will make validation at the beggining and it'll be lots of better for you r ussers

Comment: @MarekSzmalc check https://stackoverflow.com/a/69026840/823454

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```js
$('#deleteamc').on('click',function(e) {
    
    event.preventDefault();
var form = this;
    
        swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "All data related to this AMC ID will be parmanently deleted",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, DELETE it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
   form.submit();
   } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "AMC Record is safe :)", "error");
 
  }
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form method="POST" id="deleteform">
        <input type="hidden" name="amccode" id="amccode" value="<?php echo $row['amccode']; ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteamc" name="delete" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                Delete
        </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Replace**

You code is fine just replace
`$this.submit();` to `$( "button[name=submit]" ).trigger('click');`

Answer (score 0):

**Just Do like this one**

```js
$('.finalpost').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'Before post please recheck all transaction and your closing balance is correct, As you cannot alter/delete the transaction after post?',
        icon: 'warning',
        buttons: ["Make Changes", "Yes!"],
    }).then(function(value) {
        if(value){
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Post" name="post" class="btn btn-primary finalpost" style="background:#ff5733 !important; color:white !important;">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you guys want Sweet alert with native HTML form validation, check this way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $invoiceForm = $('.form-create');
                if (!$invoiceForm[0].checkValidity()) {
                    $invoiceForm[0].reportValidity()
                } else {
                    swal({
                        title: "Are you sure?",
                        text: "Did you check all the inputs and calculations?",
                        type: "warning",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                        confirmButtonText: "Yes, Submit!",
                    }).then(function (result) {
                        $invoiceForm.submit();
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `Vanilla Javascript` version should you have multiple submit buttons. **No jQuery is needed**.

```
<button class="submit" type="submit" 
     data-confirm="Are you sure you want to submit this?" 
     data-icon="warning" 
     data-color="#e55353">
       Submit
</button>
```

```
        document.querySelectorAll('.submit').forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                let form = this.closest('form');
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: this.getAttribute('data-icon'),
                    text: this.getAttribute('data-confirm'),
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
                    cancelButtonText: 'No',
                    iconColor: this.getAttribute('data-color'),
                    confirmButtonColor: this.getAttribute('data-color'),
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        form.submit();
                    }
                })
            })
        });
```