# Sweetalert package and jQuery submit() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, sweetalert

Using sweetalert library. Here's my form:

```
<form id="delete-currency" style="display:inline;" method="POST" action="/admin/currency/7">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="sIgpTKlPJ4Z3Co4daRwGpZ8rz10TCM6Ynre8sdsdsd">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>
```

7 - is an item id.

Then i am using confirm window (sweetalert):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btn-delete').click(function() {
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "blablabla!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, i am sure",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel"
        },
        function(isConfirm) {
            $('#delete-currency').submit();
        });
    });

</script>
```

I have a resource controller, which accepts delete method with currency id. However if i use sweetalert with jquery `submit()` it always sends "1" instead of actual `$currency->id`

My controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    dd($id);
    $currency = Currency::findOrFail($id);
    $currency->delete();
    alert()->success('asdasdsadad', 'Success')->persistent('close');
    return redirect('/admin/currency');
}
```

dd($id) shows "1" all the time.

routes.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function() {
    Route::resource('currency', 'CurrencyController');
});
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Could you show me your route please?

Comment: Try defining its own route, see if that make a difference. `Route::post('currency/{id}', 'CurrencyController@destroy');`

Comment: if i remove javascript at all and change my button to submit, it works as intended. What you suggest won't work, because problem is not in my routes, it's with jquery's `submit()`. Do you know how to send my currency id with `submit()`?

Comment: Well your id is being submitted by your action `/admin/currency/7`

Comment: Is the url correct in the address bar of your browser after submission?

Comment: My url is "/admin/currency/1" all the time, though actual id is 7. Magic...

Comment: Very strange, there should be no reason for it to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
 $('.btn-delete').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
     text: "blablabla!",
     type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
}, function(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) form.submit();
});
```

})

I think this will give you the right value.

Hope it helps

Comment: Your line `//post the form` - you mean to post with AJAX? If yes, i don't need ajax there. Also with your code my delete request would be submitting on the page load, i don't need that. I want it to fire when a user press "DELETE" button. `currency:258 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !` So it's impossible to do with `click()` ?

Comment: updated my post to meet your requirement. Please check :)

Comment: Not working, complains about token. Why is it a bad idea using `click()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785241/difference-between-handling-form-submit-or-an-input-type-submit-click-e

Comment: Can you try one more update instead of passing id in the url, Use hidden field & pass it to server. It will surely fix the issue `<input type='hidden'` value='7' name='id' /> `

Comment: currency:258 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! This is the actual cause. You should look into it & get it fixed. That's it

Comment: It's actually complains about your code: https://yadi.sk/i/Nfdoug3U343JkE

Comment: Lol, Please check what I did. I am using !isConfirm flag inside if condition not in the function parameter

Comment: Now it complains about Unexpected token "if" ... wtf... https://yadi.sk/i/sED9i9m_343N4Q What i am doing wrong?

Comment: I have corrected my snippet, swal() should be closed & then if condition should be checked

Comment: No errors now, but clicking on my submit button does nothing now. *cking sweetalert...

Comment: Change button type to submit `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete">`

Comment: if i change to submit type, then sweet alert not firing its modal window. If i'm not using Sweetalert, then everything works as expected.

Comment: Why you need Sweetalert if you are reloading the page. Surely with submit button it will not pop-up the sweet alert. It its ajax call then swal makes sense.

Comment: i'll explain now. It's an admin panel with lists of all my pages. Take a look at it: https://yadi.sk/i/qvR6YCLl343XbG hope you'll get my idea.

Comment: I have updated my snippet. Check it. Plus,this link would be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164151/sweet-alert-continue-submitting-form-on-confirm

Comment: works now! Thank you very much. You didn't got my idea at the start?

Comment: Yes.. In your screenshot I got to know what you are trying to do. But glad that we fixed it Cheers :)