# Cannot submit form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert2

I have a problem at submitting a form within sweetalert2 using jquery.

Here's the code that i have:

```
<?=form_open_multipart('controller_path','id="form_service"' , ''?>
<input type="button" name="update" id="submit-operate" value="Submit To Operated" class="btn btn-success" onclick="service.submitService()"/>
<?= form_close(); ?>
```

and this is service.js:

```
submitService: function(){
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You will submit this service to the next phase",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Submit'
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
                $("#form_service").submit()
            }
        });
    }
```

The sweetalert works as well, and when I do the `console.log` in `if(result.value)` it shows on the console, but the form doesn't submit. Can somebody show me the correct way? Thank you.

Comment: Check this out: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220914/sweetalert-package-and-jquery-submit-not-working-correctly

Comment: @AnusAhmad thanks, but it still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
submitService = function(){
     var form = $("#form_service");
            swal({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You will submit this service to the next phase",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Submit'
            }).then((result) => {
              if (result.value) {
                    form.submit(); //semicolon in the end
                }
            });
        }
```